# VMware Workstation 7 C/C++ Compile Workload Performance

Tags: linux, gcc, compilation, benchmarking, vmware

Can anyone point me to VMware workstation benchmarks for compile workload?

Been looking for a while and I can't find any. It's a bit weird - this is supposedly a developer oriented product. Full compile of our project usually takes about 4 minutes.

I am currently using VMware workstation for development. Guest OS is Linux and the host is Windows. I don't use much of the VMware workstation features like snapshots - I have my code repository for that and I can re-create my dev environment within 10 minutes tops. I just prefer Windows font rendering, so I ssh (putty) to my VM and develop from console.

I am wondering how much compile performance I am sacrificing versus native. If there is a considerable difference (30% or more), perhaps it is more practical to have a dedicated/native dev box.

Comment: For what it's worth, newer chips (with hardware virtualization support) make a big difference. I upgraded from an old Pentium E2180 to a Xeon X3440 and saw compile times inside VirtualBox drop 30% more than I expected from clock rates alone.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's still the case, but it used to be that building Firefox inside a Linux VM was actually faster than building it on the same Windows host!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For background, In 2005/2006 or so I worked on a very large project based on linux and using Tuxedo and Informix.

We virtualized the environment for each developer with VMWare and also had 2 separate groups of machines for Q/A and staging.

Builds were done on the machines for which they were targeted for "consistency."

Unless we asked for make to run more jobs than we had CPUs (make -j 4 on a 2 CPU machine) the virtual machines build time was within 5 to 10% of the real machines.

As I recall, our makefiles reported build times of apx 18 to 20 minutes on a real machine and 20 to 24 on a virtual machine.

The virtual machines also bogged down from heavy network or disk IO.